# How To Re-create a Cut Section of an image properly?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fill

Below is an example image, where the top of the girl's head is cut, and pixels are missing.

Is there an easy way re-create the pixels in that section properly ?
Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is *no automated* method which will generate artwork, matching existing pieces, where no art exists.

One needs to ***recreate*** any missing portion *manually*. Whether that means you **draw** areas which are missing, or utilize tools such as the **Clone Stamp Tool*, or things such as Content Aware fill... it all must be done *manually*.

There's no "button" or "command" that will generate *matching* artwork from scratch.

Comment: Even manually, Content Aware fill might not yield usable results.

Comment: @nocturns2 agreed, especially with *illustrations*.